# Shutting down embedded Tomcat application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssh, intellij-idea

I have an application that has embedded Tomcat 7 within it.

What's the best way to shutdown the application (and Tomcat)?

1. While running it in the Intellij or Eclipse IDE (e.g. to restart).
2. While running it on a production Linux server (e.g. to redeploy) using SSH.

One option that I am looking at is using a shutdown hook within the application that would incorporate the code for shutting down Tomcat. Is that the correct approach? If it is, what would trigger the shutdown? For the IDE, would just stopping the application work? On the server, what SSH command would be used to trigger the shutdown?

Note: I am not using Maven.